# Using Key Filter to filter DVWP

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata, data-view-web-part

I'm using a DVWP to display the contents of a document library. I've enabled Metadata Navigation for the library and when I navigate to the library's `AllItems.aspx` page it displays the correct Key Filters panel in the left navigation bar.

I would like to use the same Key Filters panel to filter either a LVWP or preferably a DVWP on a Web Part page that is the landing page for my site. I've been unable to find any useful information on how to do this.

Is there any way to wire the Key Filters panel to a LVWP or DVWP? How to get SharePoint to render the Key Filters panel on pages other than the `AllItems.aspx` page (without turning on *Tree view* navigation)?

UPDATE:

Just to be a little more explicit, if I turn on Metadata Key Filters for the list I get this in the left nav bar:

[image]

I have a SitePage where I'm using a list view of the same list and I would like to be able to display the Key Filters on that page and wire it up to filter my list view. HTH.

Comment: Data View Web Part and List View Web Part for those who are unsure.

Comment: or you can use query string as post in the following link: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55184/how-to-filter-dataview-webpart-dvwp-from-query-string

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think you would have to use a Content By Query WebPart to achieve what you want to do.

You need to add them as data mappings not as Common fields though:

```
DataMappings
DataMappingViewFields
```

[edit] Erikb has an example in a previous question: [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3287/sharepoint-2010-cqwp-and-managed-metada-columns)

I hope this gives you your desired result. You can use the xslt to pretty much format however you want and JQuery to do more advanced touches.

If could you provide a diagram to show more exactly what you require.